# Oracle 12c - sql to find out of order rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c

I have a table with following columns:

```
FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(30);
STATUS VARCHAR2(2);
DEPT_ID NUMBER;
DEPT_SUB_ID NUMBER;
CREATE_DATE DATE;
```

sample data:

```
FILE_NAME                 STATUS  DEPT_ID   DEPT_SUB_ID  CREATE_DATE
---------                 ------- --------  -----------  ----------
TEST_20180806222127       C       1         10           07-AUG-18 01.04.47.821795000 AM
TEST_20180806221940       C       1         10           07-AUG-18 04.12.20.957400000 AM
TEST_20180806221733       C       1         10           07-AUG-18 03.35.27.809494000 AM
TEST_20180805202020       C       1         20           06-AUG-18 02.24.47.821795000 AM
TEST_20180805201640       C       1         20           06-AUG-18 00.42.20.957400000 AM
TEST_20180805201530       C       1         20           06-AUG-18 03.55.27.809494000 AM
```

`FILE_NAME` consists of: `<TYPE>_<DATETIME>` 
I want to write a query for each `DEPT_ID`, `DEPT_SUB_ID` to determine which files with `STATUS = 'C'` were created out of order based on the `<DATETIME>` on `FILE_NAME` and `CREATE_DATE` field. In this example, for `DEPT_SUB_ID = 10`, file `TEST_20180806222127` was created before the other 2 based on the `DATE_TIME` on the file name so I would need to return only this file name in result for `DEPT_SUB_ID = 10`. For `DEPT_SUB_ID = 20`, result should contain `TEST_20180805201640` and `TEST_20180805202020` since both were created before `TEST_20180805201530`, which is considered out of order.

Expected results from query will output all file_name's which were created before it's order of run.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign two rankings to each row, one based on the order of the timestamp embedded int he file name, or other on the order of the creation date:

```
select yt.*,
  row_number() over (partition by dept_id, dept_sub_id
    order by to_date(substr(file_name, -14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) as rn_file_name,
  row_number() over (partition by dept_id, dept_sub_id
    order by create_date) as rn_create_date
from your_table yt;

FILE_NAME           S    DEPT_ID DEPT_SUB_ID CREATE_DATE                   RN_FILE_NAME RN_CREATE_DATE
------------------- - ---------- ----------- ----------------------------- ------------ --------------
TEST_20180806221733 C          1          10 2018-08-07 03:35:27.809494000            1              2
TEST_20180806221940 C          1          10 2018-08-07 04:12:20.957400000            2              3
TEST_20180806222127 C          1          10 2018-08-07 01:04:47.821795000            3              1
TEST_20180805201530 C          1          20 2018-08-06 03:55:27.809494000            1              3
TEST_20180805201640 C          1          20 2018-08-06 00:42:20.957400000            2              1
TEST_20180805202020 C          1          20 2018-08-06 02:24:47.821795000            3              2
```

Then filter to see the mismatches:

```
select file_name, status, dept_id, dept_sub_id, create_date
from (
  select yt.*,
    row_number() over (partition by dept_id, dept_sub_id
      order by to_date(substr(file_name, -14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) as rn_file_name,
    row_number() over (partition by dept_id, dept_sub_id
      order by create_date) as rn_create_date
  from your_table yt
)
where rn_file_name > rn_create_date;

FILE_NAME           S    DEPT_ID DEPT_SUB_ID CREATE_DATE                  
------------------- - ---------- ----------- -----------------------------
TEST_20180806222127 C          1          10 2018-08-07 01:04:47.821795000
TEST_20180805201640 C          1          20 2018-08-06 00:42:20.957400000
TEST_20180805202020 C          1          20 2018-08-06 02:24:47.821795000
```

And you can add a filter for a specific ID or sub-ID, either in the inner or outer query, if you don't want to see them all at once.

Comment: You beat me to the draw :)

Comment: Had to happen eventually *8-)