# How to find out of order elements using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list in c# that has two datetime fields: DatePaid and DateEntered.  I want to find the out of order elements.  This is easy enough, old school.  Sort the list by DatePaid, and then do a foreach through the list, capturing the DateEntered into a local variable, (lastDateEntered).   Each time through the loop, we first compare the DateEntered and lastDateEntered.  If the DateEntered is ever less than the lastDateEntered, then the prior row would be an out of order row.

```
| DatePaid | DateEntered | comments     |
|----------|-------------|--------------|
| 1/1/2019 | 1/1/2019    |              |
| 2/1/2019 | 2/2/2019    |              |
| 3/1/2019 | 3/1/2019    |              |
| 4/1/2019 | 5/2/2019    | out of order |
| 5/1/2019 | 5/1/2019    |              |
```

In SQL (ignore this paragraph if you don't care about SQL), it's easy enough to create two [CTE's](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) (which is like a subquery): one sorted by DatePaid, the other sorted by DateEntered.   We use the Row_Number() function to add an extra field that has the CTE sorted.  Then we join on the row number of each CTE, and then only select the rows where the dates are not equal from one CTE to the other.  Similar to [Oracle 12c - sql to find out of order rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729019/oracle-12c-sql-to-find-out-of-order-rows) although the answer didn't use CTE's.  I think I could muddle my way through linq doing something similar but I'm not sure it would be easier than the foreach loop method.

Is there a better Linqish way?

Comment: I dont understand the example. How can it enter on 2/2/2019 and bei paid on 2/1/2019? no matter what date format used, it would enter after it was paid...

Comment: Do you need to determine which item is out of order? Or just that the list is not in order?

Comment: Why do you have to sort the records to find the out-of-order ones? By sorting them you correct their bad ordering. Also it is not clear to me what are the dates in the list. The format is Day-Month-Year or Month-Day-Year?

Comment: The list is in-memory, not on a database, correct? Why is 5/2/2019 out of order and not 5/1/2019???

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Based on the out of order comment, it must be M/D/Y.

Comment: BTW, the LINQ to Objects equivalent of `RowNumber` is the two argument `Select`: `list.Select((item,rowNumber) => ...)`.

Comment: i was using month, day, year.   The second entry is to indicate it is ok to have an entry date after a date paid.  That you means you are recording it after the fact.   The one marked out of order is out of order because according to the entry date it got entered after the 5/1 date.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, it's already in memory.   Thank you for the tip about RowNumber.

Answer (score 3):

Using a LINQ extension that is based on the APL Scan operator (like `Aggregate`, only it returns the intermediate results), that combines the prev and cur elements of a list to get a new value, the solution is straight forward.

First, the extension method:

```
// TRes combineFn(T prevValue, T curValue)
public static IEnumerable<TRes> ScanByPairs<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, TRes> combineFn) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator())
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prev = srce.Current;

            while (srce.MoveNext())
                yield return combineFn(prev, prev = srce.Current);
        }
}
```

And now you can test each date field:

```
var ansdp = list.ScanByPairs((prev, cur) => new { OrderNotOkay = prev.DatePaid >= cur.DatePaid, prev })
              .Where(op => op.OrderNotOkay)
              .Select(op => op.prev)
              .ToList();

var ansde = list.ScanByPairs((prev, cur) => new { OrderNotOkay = prev.DateEntered >= cur.DateEntered, prev })
              .Where(op => op.OrderNotOkay)
              .Select(op => op.prev)
              .ToList();
```

(Which gives me the obvious idea to write `WhereByPairs` (and its many companions).)

If you don't want to use an extension method, you can simulate the same thing using the LINQ `Zip` method:

```
var ansde2 = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (prev, cur) => new { OrderNotOkay = prev.DateEntered >= cur.DateEntered, prev })
                 .Where(op => op.OrderNotOkay)
                 .Select(op => op.prev)
                 .ToList();
```

And, of course, you can encapsulate the order testing in an extension method:

```
public static class ListDateExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> OutOfOrder<T, TField>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TField> selectorFn, Comparer<TField> cmp = null) {
        cmp = cmp ?? Comparer<TField>.Default;
        return src.ScanByPairs((prev, cur) => new { OrderNotOkay = cmp.Compare(selectorFn(prev), selectorFn(cur)) >= 0, prev })
                  .Where(op => op.OrderNotOkay)
                  .Select(op => op.prev);
    }
}
```

And then you can test the fields with:

```
var ansdp = list.OutOfOrder(l => l.DatePaid).ToList();
var ansde = list.OutOfOrder(l => l.DateEntered).ToList();
```

Comment: Your `ScanByPairs` extension method looks very similar to [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s [Pairwise](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Pairwise__2.htm) method. 

Comment: I find MoreLinq (like LINQ and C#) not as orthogonal/general as I would always like (e.g. why doesn't `Append` take a `params T[]` as the last parameter? Why doesn't `GenerateByIndex` have a version that takes an end value / count? (`GenerateByIndex().Take()` seems overly obtuse/verbose to me.)

Comment: It is great for stealing source code though. 
You can check [Atif](https://github.com/atifaziz)'s implementation [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs). It is almost identical with yours, with the twist of returning the result of a nested function instead of yielding directly. I don't know why he is doing this.

Comment: Btw `Append`ing a T[] would be identical with using the build-in `Concat`. Maybe this is why he left it out.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Looking at the code, I see it is like mine. The pattern where they return a local function allows for immediate exceptions on invalid arguments at the call to the method, not at the first iteration of the stream. The point of `Append<T>(IEnumerable<T> head, params T[] tail) => head.Concat(tail)` is that you can call it `list.Append(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Aaaa, nice! I had totally forgotten this trick for validating an iterator's arguments up front! About `.Append(1, 2, 3)` you are right, it would be very handy. 

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
// your items
var items = new Item[]
{
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-02-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-02-02")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-03-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-03-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-04-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-02")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01")),
    new Item(DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-05-01")),
};

// order the elements by DatePaid descending
// the aggregate accumulator will contain the last DateEntered
// and the list of elements out of order
var outOfOrder = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.DatePaid)
    .Aggregate(
        new { LastDate = DateTime.MaxValue, Accumulator = new Item[0] },
        (a, i) => new { LastDate = i.DateEntered, Accumulator = i.DateEntered <= a.LastDate ? a.Accumulator : a.Accumulator.Concat(new[] { i }).ToArray() });
```

It is not very elegant, but it shows a way of doing it and you can probably refactor it to something more readable.

Otherwise you may order the array and do something like:

```
// we have to materialize the array, so we can use it in the Select
var ordered = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.DatePaid).ToArray();
var outOfOrder = ordered
    .Select((item, index) => new { OutOfOrder = index > 0 && item.DateEntered > ordered[index - 1].DateEntered, Item = item })
    .Where(i => i.OutOfOrder)
    .Select(i => i.Item);
```

Or something like:

```
var ordered = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.DatePaid);
var skipOrdered = ordered.Skip(1).Concat(new[] { new Item(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue) });
var outOfOrder = ordered.Zip(skipOrdered, (old, curr) => new { old, curr })
    .Where(i => i.old.DateEntered < i.curr.DatePaid)
    .Select(i => i.curr);
```

But I'm not sure if performance-wise, any of these is much better than a foreach loop.